# JAVA. Duda respecto a buscar un String en un Array bisimensional

Tags: java, array, string

Busco que el operador ingrese dos datos relacionados, luego dos más y así continuamente.
Cuando requiera buscar un dato, pueda ingresar cualquiera de los dos datos relacionados y se mostraria el otro. Ej: Nombre y Apellido, si escribo nombre, me devuelve el apellido.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Ingrese el número de paises que va a ingresar: ");
    int k = sc.nextInt();

    String[][] dato = new String[2][k];

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; i < 2; j++){ 
            if (j==0){    
            System.out.print("Ingrese el país: "); 
            dato[0][i] = sc.nextLine();
            }
            if (j==1){    
            System.out.print("Ingrese la capital: "); 
            dato[1][i] = sc.nextLine();
            }
        }  
        String search = null;


        while (!"FIN".equals(search)){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dato a buscar: ");
        search = sc.nextLine();    

        String resultado = Arrays.stream(dato)
                         .filter(s -> s.equals(dato))
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(null);
        if (resultado != null) {
        System.out.println("");
        } else {
        System.out.println("No Encontrado");
        }
        }  
    }
}
```

Desde el "while" ya no se como lograr obtener  el resultado esperado.

De antemano, agradezco su ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con el siguiente programa:

```
public class PairsTest {

    private static String[][] countries;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PairsTest.fillData();
        PairsTest.searchData();
    }

    private static void fillData() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Ingrese el número de países que va a ingresar: ");
        int num_paises = sc.nextInt();

        PairsTest.countries = new String[num_paises][];
        for (int i = 0; i < num_paises; i++) {
            String[] pair = new String[2];
            String readed = "";

            System.out.print("Ingrese el país: ");
            while (readed.equals("")) {
                readed = sc.nextLine();    
                pair[0] = readed;
            }
            System.out.print("Ingrese la capital: ");
            readed = sc.nextLine();
            pair[1] = readed;

            PairsTest.countries[i] = pair;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void searchData() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese dato a buscar: ");
            String readed = sc.nextLine();    

            if ("FIN".equals(readed)) {
                break;
            }

            String result = "";
            for (String[] pair : PairsTest.countries) {
                if (pair[0].equals(readed)) {
                    result = pair[1];
                    break;
                }
                if (pair[1].equals(readed)) {
                    result = pair[0];
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.print("Resultado de buscar '" + readed + "': ");
            if (result.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("No Encontrado.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }  
    }

} // class
```

Un resultado posible con dos países sería:

```
Ingrese el número de países que va a ingresar: 2
Ingrese el país: France
Ingrese la capital: Paris

Ingrese el país: Spain
Ingrese la capital: Madrid


-----------------------------------------------
Ingrese dato a buscar: 
Madrid
Resultado de buscar 'Madrid': Spain

Ingrese dato a buscar: 
xxx
Resultado de buscar 'xxx': No Encontrado.

Ingrese dato a buscar: 
Paris
Resultado de buscar 'Paris': France

Ingrese dato a buscar: 
FIN
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema al usar filter es que no podras obtener el dato relacionado, yo creo que la alternativa mas sana y sin recurrir a librerias externas seria asi:

```
String[] paises = dato[0]; //esto lo hago solo para que sea mas comodo leer el codigo
String[] capitales = dato[1];

String resultado = "";
for (int i=0;i<paises.length;i++) {
   if (paises[i].contains(search)) { //o equalIgnoreCase() si la busqueda tiene que ser exacta
      resultado = capitales[i];
      break;
   }
}
```